# newb can't download betfair demo from github in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, git, betfair

I've not used GIT before so tried "Import > GIT > Projects from Git" and selected "Clone URI" thinking I should be able to follow my nose.

First I just pasted the URL (https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/tree/master/java) into the dialog and it gave me an error
"...https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/tree/master/java/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found..."

I can browse the source fine in a web browser so I'm assuming its nothing to do with authentication.

I've tried adding http.sslVerify=false to no avail.

I've tried making all lowercase to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following url: `https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code.git`, obtained from:

[image]

Comment: I've installed Eclipse Luna. Just tried importing a git project. Followed all the default options. Got to the option where I select which project and it only shows the android one. Any Idea why it doesnt show the java one? I've got around by importing it as a maven project but im guessing I'll be losing the git functionality in eclipse.

Comment: @TedTrippin From what I see only the android sample has an eclipse .project defined. The java sample has only maven, so you are on the right track using maven import. You will not lose any git functionality. Just make sure that the git plugin is enabled in eclipse and you are good to go.